# NVIDIA DLI final assessment

Tags: deep-learning, nvidia

I'm taking NVIDIA DLI Deep Learning in Intelligence Video Analytics and Computer Vision course.
I have problem while I'm doing final assessment. here is Links for help you understand what I've been doing.( https://medium.com/altotech/part-6-final-assessment-deep-learning-in-intelligence-video-analytics-and-computer-vision-workshop-318bb0f5458e )

I'm following that article's guide fixing some errors.
here's the code:

```
import caffe
import cv2
import sys
def deploy(img_path):
    caffe.set_mode_gpu()
    MODEL_JOB_DIR = '/dli/data/digits/20191203-135349-c1c3'
    ARCHITECTURE = MODEL_JOB_DIR + '/' + 'deploy.prototxt'
    WEIGHTS = MODEL_JOB_DIR + '/' + 'snapshot_iter_540.caffemodel'
    # Initialize the Caffe model using the model trained in DIGITS. Which two files constitute your trained model?
    net = caffe.Classifier(ARCHITECTURE, WEIGHTS,
                           channel_swap=(2,1,0),
                           raw_scale=255,
                           image_dims=(256, 256))

    # Create an input that the network expects. This is different for each project, so don't worry about the exact steps, but find the dataset job directory to show you know that whatever preprocessing is done during training must also be done during deployment.
    input_image= caffe.io.load_image(img_path)
    input_image = cv2.resize(input_image, (256,256))
    DATA_JOB_DIR = '/dli/data/digits/20191203-135017-353f'
    mean_image = caffe.io.load_image(DATA_JOB_DIR + '/mean.jpg')
    input_image = input_image-mean_image
# Make prediction. What is the function and the input to the function needed to make a prediction?
    prediction = net.predict([input_image])
# Create an output that is useful to a user. What is the condition that should return "whale" vs. "not whale"?
    if prediction.argmax() == 0: 
        return "whale"
    else:
        return "not whale"

!python submission.py '/dli/data/whale/data/train/face/w_1.jpg'
```

the error messege was:

> File "submission.py", line 22
>       prediction = net.##REPLACE WITH THE FUNCTION THAT RETURNS THE OUTPUT OF THE NETWORK##([##REPLACE WITH THE INPUT TO THE FUNCTION##])

```
                                                                                                                                  ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I've been replacing "input_img" to "output_img"

If anyone knows how to handle this answer me please

Answer (score 0):

mean_image = caffe.io.load_image('/dli/data/digits/20180707-144641-812f/mean.jpg')

```
input_image = input_image-mean_image


# Make prediction. What is the function and the input to the function needed to make a
```

prediction?

```
prediction = net.predict([input_image])
```